# Tabbing Between Different Projects in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I recently switched from Windows to OS X.  One of the things I was able to do on a Windows machine was to tab between different project using the Alt + Tab combination of keys.  When I try doing the same with Cmd + Tab on the Mac, I can only switch between different applications.  Is there a way for me to switch between different projects within PHPStorm using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Cmd + tilde (⌘~).

It allows you to cycle through windows, supported by most OS X applications.  You'll never look back!

Comment: By chance know how to do it in linux?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X go to

`Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Move focus to next window`

and set your shortcut to alt+tab.

Done.